# Debian boots on one Mac but not another

Tags: debian, dual-boot, boot-loader, refit

I'm trying to boot Debian from a USB Hard Drive (using rEFIt as a boot loader), and am successful on two newer-model MacBook Pros and a Hackintosh (no surprise there), but I'm not successful on several other Mac computers at my university.

rEFIt loads just fine and sees my Debian partition, but when I try to boot it, it gives the error:

> no bootable device - insert boot disk and press any key

I've read that this can be caused by several things, but I believe the fact that I can boot on some Macs eliminates most of these possibilities.

I'm not terribly well-versed in bootloaders and how they interface with the firmware, which seems to be one of the last remaining solutions, so I would appreciate some troubleshooting help.